# Parsing emails with RegEx and storing in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, email, pandas

My problem involves creating code that is robust enough to parse specific data out of 100's of emails that are all worded differently. These emails are all in txt form, and I need the same data out of all of them. Here are two example emails:

```
1) Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish for lease
   From: Claire Fitz-Gerald 
   Date: 11/15/2013 3:02 PM

   NEFS 11 has the following fish for lease:

   -GOM Cod up to 5,000 lbs (live wt) @ 1.40 lbs
   -American Plaice 2,000 lbs      .60 lbs or best offer



2) From: Claire Fitz-Gerald 
   Date: 9/5/2014 9:52 AM
   Subject: NEFS 5 Available Fish

   All,
   NEFS 5 has the following fish available for lease/trade:

     GB EAST cod: 954 lbs @ $0.83
     GB EAST cod: 1,046 lbs to trade for 1,830 lbs GB WEST cod
     GB blackback: 30,000 lbs @ $0.07
     GOM blackback: 800 lbs @ $0.03
     white hake: 6,322 lbs @ $0.13
     pollock: 22,000 lbs @ $0.015
     redfish: 14,000 lbs @ $0.015
     GB yt: 1,873 lbs @ $1.13
     GB yt: 5,127 lbs to trade for 10,254 lbs SNE yt
```

The data I need from all these emails is as follows, with data pulled from example 1) as an example:

Sector: NEFS 11

Date: 11/15/2013

Fish Species: GOM Cod, American Plaice

Weights: 5000, 2000

Prices: 1.40, 0.60

Trade, yes/no?: for now, I am simply capturing the line that has the word "trade" on it and printing it elsewhere, to be tackled at a later date.

My code is working moderately well, but I am running into a couple major hurdles. My Sector code works. My Date code works.

**Problem 1:** My Weights code scans the text for commas, and captures the numbers adjacent to the comma. Most of the weight values are above 1,000 but not all of them are and this is ruining my data later when I try to line it all up. I am wondering if there is a wiser more efficient way to parse the weights from these files?

**Problem 2:** My Species and Prices code recognizes the fish and $ correctly, but does not delimit them when printing:

```
Fish Species: GB WEST codGB ytGB EAST codredfish
Price: 0.830.070.030.130.0150.0151.13
```

.....which is why I turned to Pandas in order to neaten up and align all the data, which almost works perfectly, but for some odd reason prints the Species in random out of order locations each time, as follows:

```
         0            1           2              3        4            5  \
0  pollock  GB EAST cod  white hake  GOM blackback  redfish  GB WEST cod   
1   1,046        1,830      30,000          6,322   22,000       14,000    
2     0.83         0.07        0.03           0.13    0.015        0.015   

              6       7        8  
0  GB blackback   GB yt     None  
1        1,873   5,127   10,254   
2          1.13    None     None
```

**AND** my code can't recognize 2 weight values (each below 1000) so it aligns species with weights improperly.

**AND** two of the lines are `Trade` and not a simple lease and thus don't provide a price....further screwing up the data. Which is why I am thinking to just export those elsewhere and either parse them later or do them by hand.

So ultimately this is what I would like accomplished: **1)** The lines with `trade` on them get captured and exported AND excluded from the rest of my RegEx search. **2)** A cleaner, more precise method is used to capture the weights because obviously my method isn't working (maybe search for "pounds|lbs" and capture the numbers that directly precede those?). **3)** A clear print out with all data aligned correctly.

I realize this isn't a simple straightforward question, and I really do apologize if it is too open ended or vague or not up to standards, but this is my dilemma and I am seeking assistance or advice. Thank you so much for any and all help.

My code:

```
import os
import email
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path = 'Z:\\stuff_text' 

data_frame = {'Species' : [],
                  'Weights' : [],
                  'Prices' : []}

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile("Available Quota|American Plaice|CC Yellowtail Flounder|GOM Yellowtail Flounder|GB blackback|GB Cod East|GB East Cod|GB Cod West|GB West Cod|GB Haddock East|GB Haddock West|GB Winter Flounder|GB Yellowtail Flounder|GB yt|GOM Cod|GOM Haddock|GOM Winter Flounder|GOM blackback|Plaice|Pollock|Redfish|SNE Winter Flounder|ME Winter Flounder|SNE Yellowtail Flounder|ME Yellowtail Flounder|White Hake|Witch Flounder|Dabs", re.IGNORECASE)
            email = f.read()
            fish_types = pattern.findall(email)
            fish_types_new = list(set(fish_types))     #makes sure each fish appears only once
            data_frame['Species'].append(fish_types_new)
            print("Fish Species:", ''.join(fish_types_new))

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'\d+,\d+ ')
            #pattern = re.compile("Pounds|lbs", re.IGNORECASE)
            email = f.read()
            weights = pattern.findall(email)
            data_frame['Weights'].append(weights)
            if weights:
                print("Weight:", ''.join(weights))

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\d+)?\.\d+')
            #pattern = re.compile("@|up to|$|Price", re.IGNORECASE)
            email = f.read()
            prices = pattern.findall(email)
            data_frame['Prices'].append(prices)
            if prices:
                print("Price:", ''.join(prices))

fish = np.array(fish_types_new), np.array(weights), np.array(prices)
fish_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(fish)
print(fish_df)
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll help you but I had fun with this [one](https://regex101.com/r/4RbEtC/1)

Comment: Thanks for being the only one to respond....but none of that RegEx worked unfortunately. It's fine though, I figured this question was asking way too much out of anyone. Thanks though

Comment: Well this question is really narrowed to only your issue and is unlikely to help any one else. Next time try to split your problem to smaller pieces, you may have more luck...

Comment: That's true. And that's honestly what I've been doing if you took a peek at the questions I've asked on my profile. It's just such a big difficult project that I figured I'd take a chance and ask this giant one.

Comment: Why it `makes sure each fish appears only once`? If a fish type could appear repeatedly in one email, what should be done about the weights - add them? And what about the prices if different?